# Include only the first entry with a certain column value

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

When using `SELECT * FROM myTable` I get a list that looks like this:

```
A    473
A    234
B    752
C    136
```

However, I don't want to get several rows with the same letter. I just want to get the first entry with a certain letter and then skip to the next, like so:

```
A    473
B    752
C    136
```

Now, [I know how to do this when I know what type of data I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql). However, I want to write a SQL command that works regardless of what the table looks like, that is, something along the lines: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE duplicates of column1 are discarded`.

**EDIT: I doesn't really need to be the first entry that gets selected for each unique column1 value. Any row will do.**

**EDIT 2: I very much would like for the sollution to work both on strings and numbers.**

Comment: What database are you using?  How do you identify what the first value is?  SQL tables have no inherent ordering.

Comment: I'm using an access database, and I'm accessing it through odbc in PHP. Regarding the ordering, I really don't care which row gets selected.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some sort of aggregate function to get the value for column2 that you want.  Example:

```
SELECT Column1, MAX(Column2)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Column1
```

You can read up on the various aggregate functions and what they do [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx).  That link is specific to SQL Server, but the same idea applies to many DBMS' out there.

Comment: Is there an alternative to using MAX if column2 has strings in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY`. `SELECT column1 FROM myTable GROUP BY column1` would work:

```
A
B
C
```

If you want column2, you'll need to pick an aggregate function, such as `MAX`. `SELECT column1,MAX(column2) FROM myTable GROUP BY column1`:

```
A    473
B    752
C    136
```

That will give each row in `myTable` with a given `column1` and the highest `column2`.

Comment: The question specifically asked for the first value in the sequence.

Comment: Like your comment above said, we don't know what "first value" means without knowing more about the table. Is there an ID column?

From the example I assumed MAX would be a good starting point to explain the use of GROUP BY.

Comment: If column2 are string values, can I still use MAX() or would I have to use something else?

Comment: Well, when trying this on when column2 contains string, I get zero rows so I guess MAX() isn't suitable for string values.

Comment: Does your table have any other columns, like an ID column?

Comment: @Speldosa If you are getting zero rows, there is some other problem. Max works with strings. You should post some sample data

Comment: Well, what really happens is that I get `-1` as output when I run `echo odbc_num_rows($myNewTable);` in PHP. I don't know how better to inspect it.

Comment: Check something other than the number of rows, the contents of column1, for example. "Using odbc_num_rows() to determine the number of rows available after a SELECT will return -1 with many drivers." -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-num-rows.php

Answer (score -1):

you can use the function "rownum"

**eg:**

```
select * from table_name where rownum < 2;
```

o/p: it wil show the first row entry.

Comment: There is no rownum function in Access SQL.