# Mysql Query: Display all unique IPs for a given user ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all the ip of the user have used till now.

```
"SELECT * FROM `logfeeds` WHERE uid=3"
```

simple query gives all the ips but what i want is to get each ip only one time.

**logfeeds** 
[image]

I want the query to return each IP only once per uid.

The screenshot has both id = 23 and id = 29, but it should show only id = 23, As id=23 and id=29 have the same ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query :

```
"SELECT * FROM `logfeeds` WHERE uid=3 GROUP BY ip"
```

This will surely work for you.

Comment: While GROUP BY works, it's better to use `distinct` as it is the more correct method.

Comment: @ Aaron Harun thanks :) i forgot distinct lol i knew it :P but was messing up with so many codes :P

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct:

From [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

```
SELECT distinct ip FROM logfeeds WHERE uid=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the IP once each time, use DISTINCT.

`` SELECT DISTINCT ip, * FROM `logfeeds` WHERE uid=3; ``

If you care about the most common IPs then use GROUP BY

`` SELECT *, COUNT(ip) as logged_in_count FROM `logfeeds` WHERE uid=3 GROUP BY ip ORDER BY logged_in_count DESC; ``

While GROUP BY works when you need the count, it's better to use `distinct` in other cases as it is the more correct method.

See: [How to select unique records by SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that `id` and `timestamp` increase in step
And that you want all columns (you did use `SELECT *`)

```
SELECT
   MIN(id), uid, ip, MIN(timestamp)
FROM
   logfeeds
WHERE
   uid=3
GROUP BY
   uid, ip
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the distinct statement

`SELECT DISTINCT(ipcolumn) FROM logfeeds` ....

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"SELECT Distinct(ip),timestamp FROM `logfeeds` WHERE uid=3"
```