# Postgres: Distinct but only for one column and latest one

Tags: postgresql, select, distinct-on

I have the following original table

[image: orginal table]

What I want is to retrieve latest history_id with distinct new_id. As follow:

[image: desired result]

I found this [distinct_but_only_one_column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913969/postgres-distinct-but-only-for-one-column) but it only contains how to retrieve distinct one column. Please help me out.

Comment: check your first result rows? i think its wrong otherwise show the your logical

Comment: Are the values for `news_headline` correct where you have shown your desired output? I'm not certain that I see how these correlate.

Comment: Are you looking for `DISTINCT ON`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, assuming your table is named `x`:

```
select * from x
where history_id in (
   select max(history_id) from x group by news_id
);
```

Output:

```
 history_id | news_id |      news_headline       
------------+---------+--------------------
          1 |       5 | My test Headline
         13 |       7 | My test Headline
          3 |       4 | New Headline
          4 |       6 | History Headline
```

This also works (and is simpler):

```
select distinct on (news_id) *
from x
order by news_id, history_id desc;
```

(but this never feels "right" to me)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
select max(history_id),news_id,newsheadline from 
table1 group by news_id,newsheadline
```

Comment: This works only if `news_headline` is the same value for all `news_id` (which it might be, but then again, it might not be).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `distinct on` you can use a window function which is usually more flexible but a bit slower than using `distinct on`

```
select history_id, news_id, news_headline
from (
   select history_id, news_id, news_headline,
          row_number() over (partition by news_id order by history_id desc) as rn
   from the_table
) t
where rn = 1
order by history_id;
```