# Return unique rows based on certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I need a query that will return distinct rows, but will not return any rows that have duplicate fruits where one of the rows is 'Approved'. Note: there will always be at most two fruits of the same name.

For example, the ideal result would be:

[image]

What I have so far is simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Food;
```

But this obviously still returns one of the rows that has the fruit 'Apple'

Comment: Can be done in several ways. Start with a `NOT EXISTS` query, try `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` etc.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of some conditional aggregation for the desired result set like

```
select fruit, min(status)
from demo
group by fruit
having sum(status = 'Approved') = 0
and sum(status = 'Bought') > 0
```

or just use `select fruit, 'Bought' as status`

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4c357/10)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Food WHERE Fruit NOT IN (SELECT (UNIQUE Fruit) FROM Food WHERE Status = 'Approved');
```

Try this query.

Comment: This is gibberish

Answer (score -1):

I think you could solve this problem a different way perhaps? To get that same result you could add a `WHERE` clause, for instance:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Food WHERE Status = 'Bought';`

You could also alter the data model so that a fruit's status is updated rather than adding another record for the same fruit (if that suits the application's purposes).

If you want to maintain the schema and get the same, I believe you can do:
`SELECT DISTINCT on (Fruit) Fruit, Status FROM Food ORDER BY Fruit, Status ASC;`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913969/postgres-distinct-but-only-for-one-column)

Comment: Distinct star is completely nonsensical

Comment: It's not gibberish because rows can be identical, not all tables have unique primary keys. Such as in OP's case.

Comment: By definition, ALL tables have PRIMARY KEYs. If they don't, then they're not tables. But this is a red herring