# Basic SQL retrieve list of items without counting it twice

Tags: sql

I have a travel log, I am trying to display a list of cities visited during a day

```
 id  day cityvisited user
  1   1        2        4  
  1   1        6        3
  1   1        4        10
  1   1        4        6

SELECT cityvisited FROM cv WHERE day = 1
```

returns the data 2, 6, 4, 4

Can I get it so it just returns 2, 6, 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select unique records by SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cityvisited FROM cv WHERE day = 1
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL you are using ?

If you are using SQL Server then you can use

```
 SELECT distinct cityvisited FROM cv WHERE day = 1
```

It works for many other DB as well.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct cityvisited from cv where day = 1

will work in tsql.

if your using a different type of sql and distinct doesnt work you could just add group by cityvisited to your query