# How do I get a list of unique row values?

Tags: sql

I have a `mail` table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mail` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userto` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `userfrom` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seen` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT userfrom FROM mail
WHERE userto = "admin"
```

however, I don't want any repeats in the output. How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select unique records by SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `DISTINCT` for non repeative record like

```
SELECT DISTINCT userfrom FROM mail
WHERE userto = "admin"
```

Check [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the DISTINCT keyword.

Useful link => http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0):

You just make the column as unique

```
ALTER TABLE mail
ADD UNIQUE (userto)
```

Use distinct [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
SELECT DISTINCT  userfrom FROM mail WHERE userto = "admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` keyword for unique values of selected columns.

Example:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT userfrom FROM mail
WHERE userto = "admin"
```

HTH!