# psql returning same result multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to get results from psql with this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM zoho, high_income 
WHERE zoho.zip = high_income.zip;
```

It retrieves that data that I want, however, it prints every result three times. For example:

```
John Doe 77808 94912
John Doe 77808 94912
John Doe 77808 94912
Jane Doe 88493 94110
Jane Doe 88493 94110
Jane Doe 88493 94110
```

I don't have three copies of each record in either table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select unique records by SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM zoho, high_income 
WHERE zoho.zip = high_income.zip;
```