# Select single value from database(when table have multiple similar values) in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns PrjId, prjname and station.
Here is my table example:

```
PrjId     prjname     station
1         test1       s1
1         test1       s2      
1         test1       s3
```

I want to fetch projects from project_detail table into a dropdown.
Here is my SQL query

```
select * from project_detail where prjname <> '' and PrjId is not null;
```

The issue is instead of one test1 project all 3 test1 are displayed in dropdown. I know I have to put some condition but I am not understanding how to do it. Pease help.

Comment: Did you try top 1 or distinct ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select unique records by SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Distinct prjname 
 from project_detail where prjname <> '' and PrjId is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You requirements are for the [DISTINCT](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/t_sql/t_sql_distinct_clause.htm) keyword

```
select DISTINCT prjname 
from project_detail 
where prjname <> '' and PrjId is not null;
```

This will give you a list of the unique prjname in your table.

However there is something that seems not quite right in that table.

If you want to describe a relationship between projects and stations where a project is present in many stations and a station could have many projects then a more correct approach could be with three ralated tables, one for the projects and one for the stations and one for the relationship between the projects and the stations

```
Project_Detail
---------------
idproj
prjname
....other specific project attributes

Station_Detail
----------------
idstation
stname
....oter specific station attributes

Project_Station
----------------
idprj
idstation
....other specific relationship attributes
....like for example dateofinstall,active etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Distinct PrjId, prjname  from project_detail where prjname <> '' and PrjId is not null;
```

It can work for you.