# SQL how to find the difference of GPA without duplication

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the difference of GPA among Semesters.

```
ID 1 Semester Fall GPA: 3.0
ID 1 Semester Fall GPA: 3.0
ID 1 Semester Spring GPA: 3.5
ID 2 Semester Fall GPA: 3.0
ID 3 Semester Fall GPA: 3.0
ID 3 Semester spring GPA: 3.2
```

Because ID 2 does not have spring GPA, i would ignore ID2.
So, how should i write to find out the difference GPA for ID 1 and ID 3?

```
ID 1 : .5

ID 3 : .2
```

I used this code below

```
select a.id, 
b.gpa - a.gpa as diff
from your_table a
join your_table b on a.id = b.id
where a.semester = 'Fall'
and b.semester = 'Spring';
```

however, the result shows ...

```
ID1 : .5
ID1 : .5
ID3 : .2
```

how can I remove the duplication? to get the resut as...

ID1 : .5
ID3 : .2

I am thinking about 'Distinct'?

Comment: Ya . you can use distinct like this query format `select distinct column_name`

Comment: Why are there seemingly duplicate rows in the first place? Is there some additional info missing or does the table itself contain duplicates?

Comment: Question is duplicated, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate, use `distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
    ,b.gpa - a.gpa AS diff
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.semester = 'Fall'
    AND b.semester = 'Spring';
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/BSQR23176)**