# How to select unique values of a column from table?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table:

```
| id | Name |
| 01 | Bob  |
| 02 | Chad |
| 03 | Bob  |
| 04 | Tim  |
| 05 | Bob  |
```

And I need to get the names which are mentioned only once (in this case: Chad and Tim)
What is the query?
Thanks.

Comment: HINT: GROUP BY, HAVING

Comment: just use Group By and count in your select

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select unique records by SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql)

Comment: @bummi This is different case. OP wants only records (value in column) that occurs only once.

Comment: just add having count(Name)=1, no need to answer, just comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT Name
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/XIIZ4307)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)  clause, like:

```
SELECT NAME FROM table GROUP BY NAME HAVING COUNT(NAME) = 1
```

Comment: Why SELECT DISTINCT? The GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Correct it was typo