# SQL select rows, where column value is unique (only appears once)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given the table

```
| id | Name |
| 01 | Bob  |
| 02 | Chad |
| 03 | Bob  |
| 04 | Tim  |
| 05 | Bob  |
```

I want to select the name and ID, from rows where the name is unique (only appears once)

This is essentially the same as [How to select unique values of a column from table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556340), but notice that the author doesn't need the id, so that problem can be solved by a `GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) = 1`

However, I need to extract the entire row (could be tens or hundreds of columns) including the id, where `COUNT(name) = 1`, but I cannot `GROUP BY id, name` as every combination of those are unique.

EDIT:

Am using Google BigQuery.

Expected results:

```
| id | Name |
| 02 | Chad |
| 04 | Tim  |
```

Comment: "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Please tell us which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: It's always a good idea to specify the expected result as well, even when you find it obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have updated the question with SQL-version and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7120fc74926ad139463c88d648f6d5b4)**

```
select * from tablename a
where not exists (select 1 from tablename b where a.name=b.name having count(*)>1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  name
2   Chad
4   Tim
```

Comment: It just beyond my understanding who is downvoting me without even understanding the answer  - if you think you've enough knowledge - explain me

Comment: I haven't voted your answer, but I noticed that in your output Tim is not mentioned. Maybe you have forgotten about (EDIT: writing down) him?

Comment: @Czarek, have you checked the demo - go there add another row for tim - it will come

Comment: If you update your post to include all rows in the fiddle and the same code in your example as the fiddle, I'll mark this as accepted

Answer (score 6):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure a name is only there once. Use `MIN()` to pick the only id for the name.

```
select min(id), name
from tablename
group by name
having count(*) = 1
```

Reading the table only once will increase performance! (And don't forget to create an index on (name, id).)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.name = t.Name AND t1.id <> t.id);
```

This would need index on `table(id, name)` to produce faster result set.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple aggregation?

```
select any_value(id), name
from t
group by name
having count(*) = 1;
```

BigQuery works quite well with aggregations so this might be quite efficient as well.

Answer (score 0):

use exists and check uqique name

```
   select id,name 
    from table t1 
   where exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t1.name=t2.name

    having count(*)=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT id,NAME
FROM
   tableName
```

Comment: This will give me every distinct combination of `id` and `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple subqueries to extract what you need.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM (SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM tableName
                                 GROUP BY name 
                                 HAVING COUNT(name) = 1) AS subQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and works for any number of columns w/o explicitly calling them out and does not require any join'ing or sub-selects

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(t) t
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
)
```