# How can I query for distinct 'task_id' in MySQL using multiple left joins and ranking?

Tags: mysql

How can i query distinct 'task_id'?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT tags.priority AS priority,  
             `dbbace69-6968-4b4d-9ac4-bcd8394beeab_tasks`.id, 
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tags.priority DESC) AS 'rank', 
             `dbbace69-6968-4b4d-9ac4-bcd8394beeab_tasks`.id AS task_id 
      FROM `dbbace69-6968-4b4d-9ac4-bcd8394beeab_tasks` 
      LEFT JOIN `dbbace69-6968-4b4d-9ac4-bcd8394beeab_task_tag` ON `task_id` = `dbbace69-6968-4b4d-9ac4-bcd8394beeab_tasks`.id 
      LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `dbbace69-6968-4b4d-9ac4-bcd8394beeab_task_tag`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` 
      WHERE `project_stage_id` = 'b30896ef-5737-4eeb-a988-346103ec2e80'  
            AND `dbbace69-6968-4b4d-9ac4-bcd8394beeab_tasks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AS subquery 
ORDER BY 'rank'
```

Comment: Did you tried `SELECT DISTINCT task_id` instead of `SELECT * ` ?

Comment: Also See [How to select unique records by SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641718/how-to-select-unique-records-by-sql), There are 4 methods you can use...

Comment: Is ``project_stage_id`` column from table ``dbbace69-6968-4b4d-9ac4-bcd8394beeab_tasks``?